# Garmin API can't authenticate (VerifierMissing error)

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0, python-requests, garmin

I am trying to build a connection to garmin API and build to Authentiocation connection, but get a error:

```
requests_oauthlib.oauth1_session.VerifierMissing: No client verifier has been set.
```

Can someone provide a complete example on how to establish the connection?
My code is:

```
consumer_key = "************"
consumer_secret = "************"
ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = \
    "https://connectapi.garmin.com/oauth-service/oauth/access_token"
AUTHORIZE_TOKEN_URL = "https://connect.garmin.com/oauthConfirm"
REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = \
    "https://connectapi.garmin.com/oauth-service/oauth/request_token"
oauth = OAuth1Session(client_key = consumer_key,
                     client_secret=consumer_secret)
oauth.fetch_request_token(REQUEST_TOKEN_URL)
authorization_url = oauth.authorization_url(AUTHORIZE_TOKEN_URL)
oauth_response = oauth.parse_authorization_response(authorization_url)
verifier = oauth_response.get('oauth_verifier')
oauth.token['oauth_verifier'] = verifier
oauth.fetch_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN_URL)
```

And the error is:

> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_session.py",
>   line 319, in fetch_access_token
>       raise VerifierMissing('No client verifier has been set.') requests_oauthlib.oauth1_session.VerifierMissing: No client verifier
>   has been set.

Comment: Hey @okuoub I got a similar issue. I get a 400 error with as message:
`Missing verifier.`
Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @okuoub are you able to solve the problem?